# How can you search in the trash, and sort deleted files by date of deletion?

Tags: snow-leopard, trash

In Snow-Leopard: Is it possible to search in the Trash, and sort deleted files by date of deletion?

Answer (score 2):

If you open up your trashcan into a Finder window. Then right click on empty space in that window go to "arrange by" and then down to date added. This is at least true in Lion I don't know what you are running or if it is true with other versions. Good luck!

Comment: Nope, it's not there in Snow Leopard. I guess they fixed it in Lion.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I can't help if it isn't in Lion. All I can do is recommend the Apple support pages. Most are really nice and through.

Comment: That just sorts items by name on my 10.7.2. (If I choose to display the Date Added column, it's empty for all items).

Comment: hmmm very strange it works on my 10.7.1 iMac. Are you sure your choosing the correct options?

Comment: Same here. All entries for date added contain ``--``.

Comment: Put your Finder in icon view mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use terminal to browse to the trash directory for your user

```
cd ~/.Trash/
```

then you can use

```
ls -la
```

to see all the files and you can search also using grep.

EDITED

to see in date order try

```
ls -lt
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it doesn't seem to order the files by date deleted. In fact they seem to be listed in alphabetical order.